# Execute code condition based on Column Header instead of statically defining

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, header

I’m trying to figure out a way to execute this code to run based on the headers in Row1 instead of defining “A1” as I am below. This works perfect, but if a column accidently gets moved I have to change it in vba manually.

So let’s say A1 = Toyota … how do I search all cells in the first row to match Toyota and then execute the condition?

```
Sub change()
 Dim car As Range
   For each car in Range("A1",Range("A" & Rows.Count).End((xlUp))
     If car = “N/A” Then
      car.Interior.Color = 65535
     end if
   Next Car
End sub
```

I have multiple conditions like this for multiple columns. So I'd just like to match up the column header to the if/then condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Find() to locate the correct column

```
Sub change()
 Dim car As Range, f as range, ws as worksheet
   Set ws = activesheet
   Set f = ws.Rows(1).Find("Toyota", lookat:=xlWhole)
   If not f is nothing then
       'got a column match
       For each car in ws.Range(f,ws.cells(rows.count, f.column).End(xlUp)).cells
         If car = "N/A" Then car.Interior.Color = 65535
       next car
   End If
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the MATCH worksheet function.

```
Sub change()

    Dim Car     As Range        ' looping cell
    Dim C       As Long         ' working column

    On Error Resume Next
    C = Application.Match(Cells(1, "A").Value, _
                          Range("B1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)), _
                          0) + 1
    If Err Then
        MsgBox Cells(1, "A").Value & " not found.", vbInformation, _
               "invalid column"
    Else
        For Each Car In Cells(2, C).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
            If Car = "N/A" Then
                Car.Interior.Color = 65535
            End If
        Next Car
    End If
End Sub
```